# I am removing class and setting another, but it is not happening?

Tags: javascript, blogger, ready

I want Ads through prescribed class removal Get ads div set up.

```
<div class='insideAd'><p>Ad</p></div>

$(function() {
  $("body").ready( function() {
    // Ads are loaded
    $(".loadAd").removeClass();
    $("insideAd").addClass();
  });
});
```

Comment: I can not understand what you are asking, but presumably there is a `.` or `#` missing from this selector `$("insideAd")`.

Comment: I think you are using these functions the wrong way - you should pass the values like .addClass('classToAdd').
also $("insideAd") would not find anything, because the dot or hash (.insideAd or #insideAd) is missing

Answer (score 1):

you may want to do something like this: first remove all classes and then add new class to matching elements:

```
$(function() {
    // Removes all classes and after it adds class 'insideAd' 
    $(".loadAd").removeClass().addClass("insideAd");
});
```

Answer (score 1):

To select an element with a class that already exists on it:

```
$(".loadAd")
```

When you do `$("insideAd")` you are trying to select a tag with that name, which doesn't exist. Even if you add the `.` with `$(".insideAd")`, you won't select any elements because none exist with this class name. To use this syntax **the class must already exist**.

To remove a class from that selected element, you should state which class to remove. Otherwise it will remove all classes from that element.

```
$(".loadAd").removeClass("loadAd")
```

Finally to add another class, you also have to pass the class to add:

```
$(".loadAd").removeClass("loadAd").addClass("insideAd")
```

Comment: _"It does not automatically remove the class that you selected."_ - Actually if you don't pass a class name to `removeClass()`, all classes will be removed from the selected element. So that part of OPs code wasn't necessarily wrong.